# SQL SUM of Maximum Values with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having the following structure.

| Fruit | Color | Origin | Popularity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | IN | 100 | 100 |
| Apple | Red | IN | 90 | 50 |
| Apple | Red | FR | 50 | 75 |
| Apple | Red | FR | 50 | 80 |
| Apple | Red |  | 20 | 20 |

I would like to get the total price (100 + 50 + 75 + 80 + 20) grouped by Fruit and Color, including sum of maximum popularity by origin (100 + 50 + 20). Below is the expected result.

| Fruit | Color | Popularity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | 170 | 325 |

I have tried group by with distinct sum but that giving wrong result.

```
select Fruit, Color, SUM(distinct Popularity), SUM(Price) FROM FRUITS_TABLE Group by Fruit, Color
```

Please share if any solution to achieve this result in a single query.

I am using MS SQL.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Fruit (
    Fruit varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    Color varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    Origin varchar(2)    NULL,
    Popularity int NOT NULL,
    Price      int NOT NULL,

    -- What is the PK?
)

INSERT INTO Fruit (Fruit, Color, Origin, Popularity, Price)
VALUES 
    ('Apple', 'Red', 'IN', 100, 100),
    ('Apple', 'Red', 'IN', 90, 50),
    ('Apple', 'Red', 'FR', 50, 75),
    ('Apple', 'Red', 'FR', 50, 80),
    ('Apple', 'Red', NULL, 20, 20)

SELECT Fruit, Color, SUM(PriceSum) AS PriceSum, SUM(PopularityMax) AS PopularityMaxSum
FROM (
    SELECT Fruit, Color, Origin,
        SUM(Price) AS PriceSum,
        MAX(Popularity) AS PopularityMax
    FROM Fruit
    GROUP BY Fruit, Color, Origin
) T
GROUP BY Fruit, Color
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try to use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function with a subquery to get maximum popularity by the origin row called `rn`.

Then use the condition aggregate function to sum all maximum popularity

```
select Fruit, 
      Color, 
      SUM(IIF(rn = 1,Popularity,0)) Popularity, 
      SUM(Price) Price
FROM (
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Fruit, Color,origin ORDER BY Popularity DESC) rn
   FROM FRUITS_TABLE
) t1
Group by Fruit, Color
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=57ef059aa1f54e178b0993927bc369b6)